# iteratively change where condition variable in redshift(pgsql)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

say, I have a result of rows of a member from a simple query.

```
select distinct mbr_id from mbr_base where location = '17957' ;
```

result would look like this.

| mbr_id | location |
| --- | --- |
| 000000011441894 | 17957 |
| 000000011437056 | 17957 |
| 000000011437981 | 17957 |
| 000000011441312 | 17957 |
| 000000011440730 | 17957 |
| 000000011482555 | 17957 |
| 000000011498476 | 17957 |

this is one of the result where location condition is filtered.
Yet, I have another 49 locations to iterate as these are my distinct locations to be examined.

Finally, I would combine all this as a one table as a result table to be ready for analytics.
For example, my Psuedo-code for Python would like

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in unique(mbr_base['location']):
    rst = '''select * from where location = 'i'; '''
    rst_df = pd.to_dataframe(rst)
    pd.concat([df,rst_df],axis=0)

display(df)
```

Can you help me to write a procedure for doing this in sql(pgsql preferrably)
Many thanks;

Comment: You select 1 column, but the result has 2 columns...

Comment: Couldn't you just use `WHERE location IN ('17957', '17958'...<all 49 locations>)` ?

Comment: thanks but I would get these locations from the query such as 'select distinct locations from mbr_base;

Answer (score 1):

If you want the individual locations, then use `in`:

```
select distinct mbr_id, location
from mbr_base
where location in ( '17957', . . . )
```

Your sample results have the location.  If you just want the `mbr_id`, then use:

```
select distinct mbr_id
from mbr_base
where location in ( '17957', . . . )
```

Now, presumably `mbr_id` is unique in `mbr_base`.  If so, remove the `distinct`.  In addition, `location` looks like a number.  If it really is a number, then drop the single quotes.  So, what you might want is:

```
select mbr_id
from mbr_base
where location in ( 17957, . . . )
```

Comment: thanks but these not what I wanted. I need to get this result using a variable in where clause which is derived from another query. (select distinct location from mbr_base;) then concatenate all result to one table (or temp table)